# Pandas df groupby dates period multiple

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dataframe where I have columns `date`, `createdAt`, `amount`,   date and created are dates and amount is float.  Example:

```
1    2020-01, 2020-01,  35.50
2    2020-02, 2020-01,  35.50
3    2020-03, 2020-01,  35.50
4    2020-04, 2020-01,  35.50
5    2020-05, 2020-01,  35.50
6    2020-01, 2020-01,  35.50
7    2020-02, 2020-01,  35.50
8    2020-03, 2020-01,  35.50
9    2020-04, 2020-01,  35.50
10    2020-05, 2020-01,  35.50
11    2020-01, 2020-01,  35.50
12    2020-02, 2020-01,  35.50
.
.
```

My expected result is to group it so I would get something like:

```
1    2020-01, 2020-01,  426
2    2020-02, 2020-01,  426
3    2020-03, 2020-01,  426
4    2020-04, 2020-01,  426
5    2020-05, 2020-01,  426
6    2020-01, 2020-02,  426
7    2020-02, 2020-02,  426
8    2020-03, 2020-02,  426
9    2020-04, 2020-02,  426
10    2020-05, 2020-02,  426
11   2020-01, 2020-03,  426
12    2020-02, 2020-03,  426
13    2020-03, 2020-03,  426
14    2020-04, 2020-03,  426
15    2020-05, 2020-03,  426
.
.
.
 and other more data with more variation to amount, but two dates would always meet with each other at some point.
```

Basically my solution was to groupby `date` and `createdAt` and aggregate `amount` with sum.

So something like:

```
firststep = df.groupby(['date', "createdAt", ])
second_df = firststep.agg({'amount': 'sum'})
reset_df = second_df.reset_index()
```

But what I get is something like:

```
1    2020-01, 2020-01,  177.5
2    2020-01, 2020-02,  177.5
3    2020-01, 2020-03,  177.5
4    2020-01, 2020-04,  177.5
5    2020-01, 2020-05,  177.5
6    2020-02, 2020-02,  142
7    2020-02 2020-03,  142
8    2020-02, 2020-04,  142
9    2020-02, 2020-05,  142
10    2020-03, 2020-03,  106.5
11    2020-03, 2020-04,  106.5
12    2020-03, 2020-05,  106.5
.
.
```

My values was supposed to meet up with each other at some point but some groupings are missing, and its starting after the previous date. Like  after `2020-01, 2020-05`,the next row is  `2020-02, 2020-02`and not `2020-02, 2020-01`

Im figuring out how to group it by the two columns and not losing some groupings. How do I get my desired output in a dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly and based upon your input and your desired output you should not group the dataframe based on both `date` and `createdAt` columns, rather you should group it just based on the `createdAt`:

```py
df.groupby("createdAt").sum()
```

##### Output

| createdAt | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01 | 426 |

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df["amount"] = df.groupby("createdAt")["amount"].transform("sum")

>>> df
       date createdAt  amount
0   2020-01   2020-01   426.0
1   2020-02   2020-01   426.0
2   2020-03   2020-01   426.0
3   2020-04   2020-01   426.0
4   2020-05   2020-01   426.0
5   2020-01   2020-01   426.0
6   2020-02   2020-01   426.0
7   2020-03   2020-01   426.0
8   2020-04   2020-01   426.0
9   2020-05   2020-01   426.0
10  2020-01   2020-01   426.0
11  2020-02   2020-01   426.0
```